# CS50 readability index calculation off

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to find the Colemen-Liau reading index based on number or letters, words, and sentences. When I plug in the sample text provided the letter, word, and sentence counts are correct but the Index always returns as -2147483648. Help!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string input);
int count_words(string input);
int count_sentences(string input);

int letters =0;
int words = 0;
int sentences = 0;

int main(void)//
{
    // user prompted for input
    string input = get_string("Input: "); //prompt user to input text

    float L = 100.0 * (letters/words);
    float S = 100.0 * (sentences/words);
    int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    letters = count_letters(input);
    words = count_words(input);
    sentences = count_sentences(input);

    printf("Letters: %i\n", letters);
    printf("Words: %i\n", words);
    printf("Sentences: %i\n", sentences);
    printf("Index: %i\n", index);
}
```

I was expecting to see the index returned as 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines

```
letters = count_letters(input);
words = count_words(input);
sentences = count_sentences(input);
```

must be executed before these lines:

```
float L = 100.0 * (letters/words);
float S = 100.0 * (sentences/words);
int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);
```

Therefore, I suggest that you swap the order of these two groups of lines in your program.

Without this swap, the lines

```
float L = 100.0 * (letters/words);
float S = 100.0 * (sentences/words);
```

do not make sense, because when those lines are executed, the variables `letters`, `words` and `sentences` all have the value `0`. A division by `0` will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).